# Reduce image PPI (Pixels Per Inch) with physical dimensions preservation

Tags: java, kotlin, image-processing, graphics

I'm developing software for the printing industry, and I need to convert high quality and high PPI(for example 300) uploaded images to low PPI(for example 40) with the same physical dimensions in inch.
for example, convert an image with 300 PPI and 10x10(inch x inch) to an image with 50 PPI and 10x10(inch x inch)
this conversion is important because we want to display a low-quality image to the user with other transparent layers, due to preview actual final printing result.


[this image is another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie4EL.jpg)


how can I do this in Java or Kotlin?

Comment: It's worth to add what would you like to do with the result. Display it? Where and how? Simply save it as another, modified file?

Comment: I'm developing software for the printing industry, and I need to convert high quality and high PPI(for example 300) uploaded images to low PPI(for example 40) with the same physical dimensions in inch, to display to the user with other transparent layers, due to preview actual final printing result.

Comment: Please clarify that in the question, not in comments

Comment: Sorry, Sure @Fureeish

Answer (score 0):

First of all, bear with me, as I am neither knowledgeable about printing processes nor about graphics terminology. This answer assumes (in my own words) that the goal is to take an image and modify it so that there are less details - fewer pixels required to display the image, but with the size preserved. If it turns out that I misunderstood the goal, please feel free to point that out. I will either try to edit the answer or come up with something new.

---

I propose the solution where you take the image, scale it down and stretch it back to the same size:

```
val path = "Y:\\our\\path\\\\to\\directory\\"

val sourceImage = ImageIO.read(File("${path}original.png"))

val smallerImage = BufferedImage(
        sourceImage.width / 2,
        sourceImage.height / 2,
        sourceImage.type
)

var graphics2D = smallerImage.createGraphics()
graphics2D.drawImage(
        sourceImage,
        0,
        0,
        sourceImage.width / 2,
        sourceImage.height / 2,
        null
)
graphics2D.dispose()
```

Here, `smallerImage` is scaled down - we are now using 4 times less pixels (because we scale by 2 both the width and the height) than we originally were using.

This achieves the goal of using fewer pixels, but the size was not preserved - it was scaled down. We now need to strech it back to the original size, but now we will be using smaller number of pixels:

```
val stretched = smallerImage.getScaledInstance(
        sourceImage.width,
        sourceImage.height,
        Image.SCALE_DEFAULT
)

val destination = BufferedImage(
        sourceImage.width,
        sourceImage.height,
        sourceImage.type
)

graphics2D = destination.createGraphics()
graphics2D.drawImage(stretched, 0, 0, null)
graphics2D.dispose()
```

Finally, we save the image to a file:

```
val destinationImageFile = File("${path}destination.png")
ImageIO.write(destination, "png", destinationImageFile)
```

And we are done. Images `original` and `destination`:

[image: Original image (16x16)] [image: Destination (changed) image (16x16)]

---

The number of saved pixels is determined solely by scale factors you use. You'll have to play with scaling to achieve exact pixel numbers savings.

Comment: thank you so much for your solution, I try this trick and it doesn't work. because when we need to reduce PPI and preserve physical dimensions, the number of pixels in height and width also must be reduced.
see the attached image that I added to the answer.

Comment: sorry: *question

Comment: @BacheSeyyed but isn't PPI strictly dependent on the printer and has nothing to do with the raster representation? In virtual representation there is no such thing as PPI - there are just pixels. In order to dusplay the exact dimensions and resolution (the exact view) of image that will be printed, you **have to** know both your screen size, its resolution and your printer's specification. It's not something that can be solved in generic way. On the other hand, if you wish to display two pictures on the screen so they appear to occupy the same space, then they have to have the same # of pixels

Comment: @BacheSeyyed in the photo you linked, you have two pictures of the same size. One cannot be 288x432 while the other being 1200x1800. Either one had to be scaled so their dimensions match during displaying. I hope I can help you with your task and I hope I can correctly understand what is the issue. However, comments section is not suited for this kind of chat - I wish we could move this to chat, but that privilege requires 20 reputation.